# Missing Java namespace in R

Tags: java, r

I was just installing an R package that appears to reference Java. I received the following error.

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.

I reinstalled Java on my computer to the latest version, and I still receive this error.  What do I need to do to get R, or is it RStudio, to recognize my computer installation of Java?

Comment: Try from shell `R CMD javareconf`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, on a lark, I googled the error, and found this answer:

https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/

Apparently, have to make sure 64-bit version is loaded. Requires manual intervention...